# convert float into integer without using javascript function, ciel(), floor()

Tags: javascript, function, reverse

I want to Convert float into integer without using JavaScript function such as  ceil(), floor()

```
 let a = 5.7
        console.log(Math.ceil(a)); console.log(Math.floor(2.3))
```

Comment: So you basically want to rewrite `ceil` and `floor`?

Comment: Why? What's wrong with `Math.ceil()` and `Math.floor()`?

Comment: Are you trying to round up like ceil does (so 5.7 would give 6 but 5.0001 would also give 6) or are you trying to actual rounding (to nearest 0.5) or ....?

Comment: If you look up how JS stores numbers you'll see it uses 64bits altogether. You can get some way with the JS bitwise operations. See for example the answer from @Spectric which gives you floor up to a certain size. For many practical purposes this will be OK, but because bitwise ops use 32 bits you lose part of the range, and the exponent part gets lost completely. What are your constraints on number sizes?

Comment: You could look at `toFixed`, e.g.: `(5.7).toFixed(0); // 6`.

Comment: You can say, Im writing ceil(). Sometime we are asked to do it without using builtin functions. So this is the way on which these functions are working.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [bitwise NOT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_NOT) operator:

```js
let a = 5.7;
let result = ~~a;
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Yes, I also used this operator. Please Check in answer.

Comment: Thsnks for your time Sir @Spectric

Answer (score -1):

Without using javascript built-in functions

```
 let a = 5.7
        console.log(Math.ceil(a)); console.log(Math.floor(2.3))
```

We can convert float into an integer by using a simple operator.

```js
let n = 12345;
  
let a = n % 10;
n = n / 10;
n = ~~n;
let b = n % 10;
n = n / 10;
n = ~~n;
let c = n % 10;
n = n / 10;
n = ~~n;
d = n % 10;
n = n / 10;
n = ~~n

console.log(a, b, c, d, n);
```

Comment: Just to make this easily useful to others could you share the console log outputs in your answer?

Comment: Why is there an empty loop? What is with all those repeating operations? Why is it necessary to log `5 4 3 2 1`? What is the equivalent of `.ceil()`? What the equivalent of `.floor()`?

Comment: I think you dont understand the example. n=12345. It is just an example which shows the use of bitwise Not operator. Loop was placed mistakenly and I delete it.

Comment: To make your answer clearer, you could have just explained that `~~` behaves the same as `floor`, with for example `~~5.1` and `~~5.9` both giving `5`. As is, it's hard to understand what you're trying to show, and whether it mimics `ceil` or `floor` given your question states both. But anyway, use `Math.floor` when you can, it will make your code less cryptic :)